# Module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR'

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

Installed all needed packages but doesn't seem to work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 5, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(slika, cv2.COLOR.BGR2GRAY)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'COLOR'
```

Comment: what does your import statement look like

Comment: import cv2
import sys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
gray = cv2.cvtColor(slika, cv2.COLOR.BGR2GRAY)
```

This is invalid, it should be `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` instead, like this:

```py
gray = cv2.cvtColor(slika, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem, I guess I made a typo.

Comment: As this has worked for you, please mark the answer as correct to help other users :)

Comment: I will as soon as I will be able to.